# I want to copy all pdf files into another directory

Tags: copy

Linux users! I'm having a issue: 
I have all pdf files in directory`Downloads`, but I want it to copy all the files in subfolder `\Download\BOOKS\`. How would I copy all files with `for` loop?

`for files in ...`

Comment: Where do you want to copy them to?  Also, `\Download\BOOKS\` is... wrong.  Is Download/BOOKS a subdirectory under your home directory?

Comment: Do you want to move to the subdirectory or promote from it ? What about conflicts ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think that you require `for` loop just for copying files. You can copy files using:

```
cp /home/username/Downloads/*.pdf /home/username/Downloads/BOOKS
```

But if you still want to use `for` loop, you can also write the below code:

```
cd /home/username/Downloads
for F in *.pdf
do
   cp "$F" /home/username/Downloads/BOOKS
done
```

Comment: The for loop doesn't work if the file names contain spaces.

Comment: @DougO'Neal Thank you for the comment. I have corrected the code. :-)

Comment: You're putting in the quotes in too late. $F is defined by the split words in the for statement. Quoting the variable later doesn't put the fields back together again.

Comment: @DougO'Neal: The code as listed here works fine. Globs are not subsequently word-split. Try it out if you like.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I made a shell script which copy this files in subdirectory. ;)

Answer (score 9):

not with a for loop but this should work to **move** the files.

```
mv /home/username/Downloads/*.pdf /home/username/Downloads/BOOKS
```

Use this to make a *copy* of the files:

```
cp /home/username/Downloads/*.pdf /home/username/Downloads/BOOKS
```

Comment: Thanks for notifying me, I forgot to change the mv to cp after copying the line.

Answer (score 7):

The existing answers are all decent, but have varying minor issues, which may or may not be problematic. Let's try to handle them.

1. Is `*.pdf` correct for all the files? I find PDFs downloaded from the internet often are `*.PDF` instead. (I suspect certain case-insensitive filesystems cause this.)
2. Are all the PDFs in the BOOKS subdirectory directly, or are there subdirectories? `BOOKS/Romance`, `BOOKS/Horror` for example.
3. Do the PDFs have file extensions at all? Sometimes they don't.
4. Are any of the files symbolically linked? Unlikely, but not hard to handle.
5. Already pointed out but bears repeating: Do any of the filenames contain spaces or other odd characters? Spaces are fairly common for human-readable-ness.

The strategy is to use `find` to locate potential PDFs, `file` to filter only actual PDFs, and then act on those filenames.

```
find -L books -maxdepth 1 -print0 | xargs -0 -n1 -I{} sh -c '[ "$(file -b --mime-type "{}")" = "application/pdf" ] && cp "{}" Download/'
```

`find -L Download/BOOKS -maxdepth 1 -print0` will locate all the filesystem entries in the subdirectory tree starting at `Download/BOOKS`, following symbolic links if needed, to a maximum depth. Increase the depth number to handle subdirectories, or remove `-maxdepth 1` to handle the whole tree.

`xargs -0 -n1 -I{}` takes multiple lines of input and runs a command repeatedly with 1 input line.

`sh -c '[ "$(file -b --mime-type "{}")" = "application/pdf" ] && cp "{}" Download/'` makes a new shell to run a test on the filesystem entry, and if it is a PDF (as determined by file extension and file contents) make a copy of it to the `Download/` directory.

Using `find` takes care of 1., 2. and 4. Using `file` takes care of 3. Using the `-print0` and `-0` arguments and careful quoting takes care of 5.

If you really needed a loop because you want to run other commands on each PDF, replace `cp "{}" Download/` with whatever is approriate. The `{}` is a pattern that xargs will replace with each filename as it runs.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know about for loops (unless you write a C program to achieve this) but this line should do it:

```
 cp -v ~/Downloads/*.pdf ~/Downloads/BOOKS/
```

The CP is copy and the * is for wildcard to select anything ending in .pdf in that directory.

Comment: I was going to list all the languages that have for loops (Bash, sh, python) but it's a lot easier to list the languages that don't here it is:

Comment: @Sam There are many languages without for loops. Scheme and Haskell, for example.

Comment: If this is a homework question it probably should be bash.

Answer (score 3):

A simple for loop should be able to do what you need, i.e. copy all PDF files under Downloads (including subdirectories) in to Downloads/BOOKS

```
cd Downloads
IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b") && for n in `find . -path ./BOOKS -prune -o -name "*.pdf" -print`; do cp -fv "$n" ./BOOKS; done
```

Note that the single quote for the find statement is the backward single quote, not the normal one.

Edited: Internal field separator needed for spaces in filenames.

Comment: Props for respecting the OPs request for a FOR loop solution, but I can't help but want to simplify that to:  `cd /foo/bar; find ./ -name '*.pdf' -exec cp -fv '{}' ./BOOKS/ \;`

Comment: This one *will* be subject to word splitting

Comment: @immortalsquish's answer is not only simpler; it is also _correct_: the code in this answer does the wrong thing when the path to any PDF under Downloads contains a space.

Comment: Good catch guys. I have updated my answer to correct for this. Good to explicitly define IFS as not everybody have this customized in their bashrc.

Answer (score 1):

A simple for loop will work, but is much more complicated than it needs to be.

```
for FILE in ~/Downloads/BOOKS/*.pdf; do
  cp "$FILE" /new/directory/
done
```

This will copy all files in the BOOKS directory to /new/directory

Comment: Doesn't work if any of the files have whitespace in the filenames.

Comment: Change `cp $FILE` to `cp "$FILE"` to prevent word-splitting, as @Doug mentions.

Comment: Also, change `/*` to `/*.pdf` to only copy `.pdf` files.

Comment: @wchargin Still would not work. $FILE will be defined by the split words in the for statement. Quoting it later is closing the barn doors after the horse has gone.

Comment: @DougO'Neal: That's not true: https://gist.github.com/wchargin/ad87571235ad0bbb02a998d4a2e2c6e3

Comment: The most beautiful solution is a bash script which code is:

Comment: `#!/bin/bash

cd /home/andrej/Prejemi
for F in *.pdf
do
 cp "$F" /home/andrej/Prejemi/KNJIGE
done `

Comment: @andrej, why do you say that that is the "most beautiful" solution? To me, a simple `cd ~/Prejemi; cp *.pdf KNJIGE/` seems clearly much better. It is simpler, using strictly fewer constructs. It is easier to read and more idiomatic. And it only invokes `cp` once, so it will be faster with lots of files.

Comment: (I'm aware that it doesn't suffice in the case where you get an "argument list too long" error, but it doesn't sound like you have that many PDFs—and if you do, then `find -exec` or `find -print0 | xargs -0` is a better solution than a `for` loop.)